# How to use xslt with attribute values as selectors ?

Tags: xml, xslt, selector

I am trying to learn xslt and i am working an xml which looks like this.

```
<Beats>
 <Beat>
   <Personal type="set">
      <Usages type="box">
       1233
      </Usages>
      <NonUsages type="box">
       4122
      </NonUsages>
   </Personal>

   <NonPersonal type="unset">
      <Damages type="box">
       6466
      </Damages>
      <NonDamages type="box">
       5544
      </NonUsages>
   </NonPersonal>

   <Confidential type="set">
      <Discounts type="box">
       1233
      </Discounts>
      <NonDiscounts type="box">
       4122
      </NonDiscounts>
   </Confidential>

 </Beat>
</Beats>
```

My Current aim is to just print out the numbers inside the inner tags. But i cannot use the names of the tags as selectors as only the attribute 'type'is of importance. I tried using the following xslt. But it didnt seem to work.

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
<html>
<body>
<h2> Test</h2>
<xsl:for-each select="//Beats/Beat/[@type='set']">
   <xsl:value-of select="[@type='box'] />
   <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

And one more thing i couldnt figure out was how to get the name of tags while using attributes as selectors. Instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="[@type='box'] />
```

which gives whats inside the tag; what can i use to get the name of the tag which contains this 'type=box' attribute ? (For. eg Usages, NonUsages, etc..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation is intended to only provide the necessary corrections to your original transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2> Test</h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*[@type='set']/*[@type='box']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (after correcting it to make it well-formed XML document)**:

```
<Beats>
 <Beat>
   <Personal type="set">
      <Usages type="box">
       1233
      </Usages>
      <NonUsages type="box">
       4122
      </NonUsages>
   </Personal>

   <NonPersonal type="unset">
      <Damages type="box">
       6466
      </Damages>
      <NonDamages type="box">
       5544
      </NonDamages>
   </NonPersonal>

   <Confidential type="set">
      <Discounts type="box">
       1233
      </Discounts>
      <NonDiscounts type="box">
       4122
      </NonDiscounts>
   </Confidential>
 </Beat>
</Beats>
```

**the (what I guess is) wanted result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2> Test</h2>
       1233
      <br/>
       4122
      <br/>
       1233
      <br/>
       4122
      <br/>
   </body>
</html>
```

**and it is displayed in the browser as**:

### Test

1233
      
       4122
      
       1233
      
       4122

---

**On your second question**:

> And one more thing i couldnt figure out was how to get the name of
>   tags while using attributes as selectors. Instead of
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="[@type='box'] />
> ```

**You want something as**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*[@type='set']/*[@type='box']">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**The complete transformation now becomes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2> Test</h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*[@type='set']/*[@type='box']">
                  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                   <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <br/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when it is applied on the same XML document (above), the result is**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2> Test</h2>Usages : 
       1233
      <br/>NonUsages : 
       4122
      <br/>Discounts : 
       1233
      <br/>NonDiscounts : 
       4122
      <br/>
   </body>
</html>
```

**and this is displayed by the browser as**:

### Test

Usages : 
       1233
      
NonUsages : 
       4122
      
Discounts : 
       1233
      
NonDiscounts : 
       4122

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I just need one more help Dimitre. Could you explain what the function name() does ? If possible could you point me to some material which will help me understand this better ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Pradep, You are welcome. `name()` produces the name of the context (current) node. See how it is defined in the XPath 1.o W3C Spec.: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-name

Comment: That helped. And one more thing Dimitre. That br tag doesnt seem to work in my browser i get the result `Test 1233 4122 1233 4122` in Firefox. Chrome doesnt work at all. The console gives the following error. `Unsafe attempt to load URL 2.xsl from frame with URL 2.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match` . Any idea why ? Should i ask these as separate questions ?

Comment: Fixed the <br> issue by changing the method from xml to html. But the chrome issue still persists.

Comment: @Pradep, I don' use Chrome, but there have been reports that it doesn't support an xml-stylesheet PI that points to a local file, due to "security" considerations. This isn't an XSLT issue at all.